# How can I deactivate INFO messages in JBoss?

Tags: java, jboss, jboss6.x

I don't like to see INFO messages in JBoss. Do you know a flag to controll the JBoss output? I would like to deactivate the INFO messages.

Comment: What version of JBoss? Are you talking about the log messages from JBoss itself, or from an application that you have deployed too it?

Comment: JBoss 6. I'm talking about the JBoss console output done by JBoss itself and a deployed application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you want to do exactly.

1. If you want to change the default log level you have such possibles:

   - go to the `profile/deploy/jboss-logging.xml` and find such line (under `root` tag, the end of the file)

     ```
     <level name="${jboss.server.log.threshold:INFO}"/>
     ```

     You can just change the `INFO` to `WARN` or other value. It changes the value permanently. Also check the log level for `CONSOLE` appender:

     ```
     <level name="INFO"/>
     ```
   - you can run JBoss with such the command:

     ```
     run.sh -Djboss.server.log.threshold=WARN
     ```
2. You you want to just turn off the console logging, you can just:

   - comment these line from the `root` category (also in the `profile/deploy/jboss-logging.xml` file)

     ```
     <handler-ref name="CONSOLE"/>
     ```
   - run JBoss and redirect all output (at least on Linux):

     ```
     run.sh &> /dev/null
     ```

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the {jboss.dir}/jboss-as/server/{server}/conf/jboss-service.xml.

Find the log4j initialization block and modify the "*DefaultJBossServerLogThreshold*" attribute as per your needs.

Comment: DefaultJBossServerLogThreshold did not exist in any of the files in my JBoss folder. I've searched with grep.

Comment: You can find these parameter but in the JBoss 5.1 version. An even than you should rather modified `profile/conf/jboss-log4j.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit {jboss.dir}/server/{server}/deploy/jboss-logging.xml

Search for a block beginning with this line:

```
<console-handler name="CONSOLE" autoflush="true" target="System.out">
```

Then edit the Warning level:

```
<level name="INFO"/>
```

The Warning-levels are TRACE,DEBUG,INFO,WARN,ERROR andFATAL (Source: [Log4J-PDF](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/logging/JBossLog4j.pdf) and [log4j-html](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html))